# Notepad++ Execute on saving certain extension

Tags: notepad++

I want to execute/run a .bat when saving files with a certain extension. I know about run and execute. But how can I only run it if it's a certain extension?

Comment: Can you provide a few more details?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to make Notepad++ check the extension you could write another batch file that is always executed. Then have that batch file check the extension and then, if required, call the wanted batch file.